# Deploy to app engine stopped working: NoClassDefFoundError GoogleLogin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm getting the following error:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-01-03 19:04:22.670
>   !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin
>       at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.ui.DeployProjectHandler.execute(DeployProjectHandler.java:67)
>       at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.ui.DeployProjectAction.run(DeployProjectAction.java:27)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4166)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1489)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1474)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4012)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3651)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

Some background information: I'm running eclipse kepler 20130919-0819, os x 10.9.1, google suite plugin 3.5.1.

Deployment now does not work on any of my projects. I recently updated the plugin and there was a message that it required java 1.7. Development was working as usual after that message and I had no problems until I tried to deploy. (When I change the java compatibility on the project I get an error that GAE required 1.7.)

This may be related to the problem I'm having with java. According to mac preferences, java 1.7 is installed yet when I start a terminal session and issue the java command to check the version, it indicated 1.6. eclipse also seems to be running on 1.6 and I can't figure out how to rectify this. It may or may not be related.

My question is: can I fix this problem in place or do I have to back out updates and reinstall? I can continue to develop but am unable to deploy until I have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to Rajeev, I have a lead but the problem is not fixed yet.

So I find the keplar eclipse.ini file. There is no -vm entry. It has the following contents:

[image]

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is 1.6.0.jdk. I assume that this is where eclipse is picking up the jvm.

So I find and add an entry in the .ini file following the pattern in eclipse wiki:

[image]

I get the following Alert:

[image]

Then I go to the Mac Java Preferences which says that java is 1.7 is installed under:

> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

This is where java gets installed when you go to java.com to install.

Then I get:

[image]

So this is like an adventure game, but not as much fun.

I see that I have to update the .ini file, but where or how do I get the right java?

Comment: Luckily I kept a copy of eclipse juno around and was able to deploy from that. Then when I restarted kepler, I got the message 'JRE version is 1.6.0; version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run Google Plugin for Eclipse." Juno must have been using an older version.

Comment: See instructions here on how to switch the version of Java that Eclipse is using on Mac OS X: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini. You need to be using a 1.7+ JDK, or some features of GPE will not work.